# How to get name of WiFi using QT quick application on Android

Tags: qt, qml, wifi, qt-quick

I am trying to develop a code to get name of wifi connected to my android phone. My code sample is

```
QStringList WiFisList;
QNetworkConfiguration cfg;
QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
auto nc = ncm.allConfigurations();
    for (auto &x : nc)
    {
        qDebug()<< "CHECK1  " << x.bearerType();
        if (x.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN)
       {  qDebug ()<<"CHECK2";
          qDebug() <<"WIFI is"<<x.name();
       }
    }
```

Output of this code is just returning me:

**(int main(int, char**)): **WIFI is "WiFi"** but my expected output is *ASUS_XOOTD*
How can I get this as output? Is something missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

check that your qt version is supporting Bearer extension for android.

Comment: hi @Kerem did you mean by bearer plugins in my Qt?.. bearer plugin is present in my QT.

Comment: it is using at qt but some qt versions of bearer plugin are not supported by ANDROID. you have to check it out to solve this particular problem. but I recommend you to use JNI to handle android properties